# WPF DataGrid does not save changed value to variable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

So, I have this little WPF snippet:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="lstCategories" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0"
              Margin="5,5,5,5" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridColumnHeader Tag="All" Click="DataGridColumnHeader_Click">All</DataGridColumnHeader>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding enabled}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding category}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Which displays data as given in:

```
lstCategories.ItemsSource = categoryList;
```

Now, when the user clicks the checkbox, I'd expect the datagrid to write this change to `categoryListItem.enabled`, but when I check the value, it says true no matter what.
How can I make the DataGrid store changes to the variable it uses as data source?

Additional Info: I've chosen the TemplateColumn-approach with an embedded checkbox because this way the user does not have to click two times to modify the check box.

**Update 1:**
I've updated the XAML to incorporate TwoWay-Binding as:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding enabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The data source variable still does not get updated.

Comment: Did you try binding `Mode=TwoWay`?

Comment: Didn't hear of that before - this is my first time with graphical applications... Were - or better: for which element - do I have to set this?

Comment: OK I'll try to verify and post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've already figured out `Mode=TwoWay` (which isn't necessary anyway, as it is the default if you don't explicitly set it). Now all you have to do is set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Very working, much wow! Thanks, now I can go to sleep in peace. Cheers!